# Use boolean value received from mysql query to update a value

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help switching a boolean value in a field in a small MySQL DB. I created an index.php that shows names and a presence field (Present/Away). For that I use a boolean. The value is clickable, this should switch the boolean value. Here the relevant code:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$qresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Present FROM personnel WHERE Inlogcode='$id'");

$result=mysql_fetch_array($qresult);
$presence = (bool)$result;

echo "ID is: " .$id . "<BR>";
echo "Boolean res is: " . $presence . "<BR>";

if ($presence)
{
    $sql="UPDATE personnel SET Present=True WHERE Inlogcode='$id'";
    $resultaat=mysql_query($sql);
}
    else
{
    $sql="UPDATE personnel SET Present=False WHERE Inlogcode='$id'";
    $resultaat=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I cannot find out how to convert the result of my query back to a true boolean value that I can use in the rest of my PHP script. Adding mysql_fetch_array seems unnecessary, but I seem to lose the boolean value as I always get all zero's or all one's. The test DB of course contains both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the update with a single query:

```
UPDATE personnel SET Present = 1 - Present WHERE Inlogcode=?
```

Consider using PDO and prepared statements. Your current query is vulnerable to SQL injection attack

Comment: And this one is a beauty in simplicity. My favourite.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$presence = $result==1?true:false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle your boolean with one query

```
'UPDATE personnel SET Present = IF (Present, 0, 1) WHERE Inlogcode="'.$id.'"'
```

mind the "." between strings and variable. You didn't do that correctly in your code.

Comment: There's no need for IF

Comment: Without the IF didn't work. But this was the first solution I tried and found to be working.